# Jquery: Split/Join String onKeyup Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I am using a function to sanitize a string with the onkeyup event. 
The following code works ok:

```
<input type="text" id="username"  maxlength="15" onkeyup="this.value=sanitize(this.value)">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function sanitize(str) {
        return str.split(/[^a-z0-9._-]/g).join('');
   }
</script>
```

I was wondering how to re-write the same code but using jquery. 
For some reason the following code doesn't fire the onkeyup event:

```
<input type="text" id="username"  maxlength="15">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#username").keyup(function(){
        return $("#username").val().split(/[^a-z0-9._-]/g).join(''); //--> this line is not working
    }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to set the value using `val()`. Also, there is no need of `split()` and then `join()`, use `replace()`.

```
$("#username").val(function(i, value) {
    return value.replace(/[^a-z0-9._-]/g, '');
});
```

```js
$("#username").keyup(function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, value) {
    return value.replace(/[^a-z0-9._-]/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" maxlength="15" />
```

I'll also suggest to use `pattern` attribute on `input`.

```
<input type="text" id="username" maxlength="15" pattern="[a-z0-9._-]{0,15}" />
<!--                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the value again

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#username").keyup(function(){
        var _val =  $(this).val().split(/[^a-z0-9._-]/g).join(''); 
        $(this).val(_val); // to set the value of input feild.
    }); 
});
```